# Thunderbird over VPN is asking to authenticate every time

Tags: email, vpn, thunderbird

I just tried to run a VPN connection and then read my email via Thunderbird. For every account, it asked me to reauthenticate.

I guess the servers are recognizing a different login location and are enforcing a new login...This appears to happen on every new VPN connection (every day).

I don't have much hope, but I wanted to ask if there is some strategy to avoid this? Or I would have to renounce using a VPN when running Thunderbird

Comment: Is it gmaill or similar using OAuth2, or traditional imap service?

Comment: yep. mostly gmail and yahoo addresses

Comment: It's not TB, it's Gmail. It will happen with any generic Client software.

Comment: Yeah...I thought so....So I guess forget about using the VPN when reading emails. Thanks